# How to resolve angular ng-options track by deep clone issue?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-track-by

`ng-options="branch as branch.name for branch in ordersItemClientInfo.branches track by branch.id"`

In my case "branches" is an array of object and each of them have field ref to so deep object (map geoObject). Angular tries to copy thats object and fails!

from angular.js:

```
getViewValueFromOption: function(option) {
  // If the viewValue could be an object that may be mutated by the application,
  // we need to make a copy and not return the reference to the value on the option.
  return trackBy ? angular.copy(option.viewValue) : option.viewValue;
}
```

I don't need a copy, I need original object to be selected. How can I make it?

Comment: I have walkaround (using ng-repeat and select by $index), but it's not clear...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to do a `JSON.stringify` (to each item before showing it) and then make the `JSON.parse` in the template whenever you want to display it?

Comment: It'll throw JSON stringify error, because object so deep